# :tsearch english vs simple dictionary performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, full-text-search

I'm following a [tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/optimizing-full-text-search-with-postgres-tsvector-columns-and-triggers) on pg_search and the author is specifying `dictionary: "english"` when the default is `"simple"`, but the author doesn't mention why.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  pg_search_scope(
    :search,
    against: %i(
      description
      manufacturer_name
      name
    ),
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        dictionary: "english",
      }
    }
  )
end
```

Say I want to do a fulltext search of 'Barack Obama' over 100,000 news articles.  Would you use the postgres english dictionary or the simple dictionary and why?  Is it faster or more accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read PostgreSQL [Full text Search Dictonary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-ISPELL-DICTIONARY)

There are

> 1) Simple dictonary(The simple dictionary template operates by
>   converting the input token to lower case and checking it against a
>   file of stop words.)
>
> 2) Synonym Dictionary(This dictionary template is
>   used to create dictionaries that replace a word with a synonym.
>   Phrases are not supported (use the thesaurus template (Section 12.6.4)
>   for that). A synonym dictionary can be used to overcome linguistic
>   problems, for example, to prevent an English stemmer dictionary from
>   reducing the word 'Paris' to 'pari')
>
> 3)Thesaurus Dictionary(A
>   thesaurus dictionary (sometimes abbreviated as TZ) is a collection of
>   words that includes information about the relationships of words and
>   phrases, i.e., broader terms (BT), narrower terms (NT), preferred
>   terms, non-preferred terms, related terms, etc.)
>
> 4)Ispell Dictionary(The Ispell dictionary template supports
>   morphological dictionaries, which can normalize many different
>   linguistic forms of a word into the same lexeme. For example, an
>   English Ispell dictionary can match all declensions and conjugations
>   of the search term bank, e.g. banking, banked, banks, banks', and
>   bank's.)
>
> 5) Snowball Dictionary(The Snowball dictionary template is based on
>   the project of Martin Porter, inventor of the popular Porter's
>   stemming algorithm for the English language. Snowball now provides
>   stemming algorithms for many languages (see the Snowball site for more
>   information). Each algorithm understands how to reduce common variant
>   forms of words to a base, or stem, spelling within its language)

Now in your case it will not check spell  or not streaming or not abbreviation not any other language difference

If you use one of the language dictionaries, such as "english", then variants of words (e.g. "jumping" and "jumped") will match each other.

so any english word which are closer will match

If you don't want stemming, you should pick the "simple" dictionary which does not do any stemming. If you don't specify a dictionary, the "simple" dictionary will be used.

Like below Example

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  pg_search_scope(
    :search,
    against: %i(
      description
      manufacturer_name
      name
    ),
    using: {
      tsearch: {
        dictionary: "english",
      }
    }
  )
end
```

So

```
Product.search("Milk") # return ["Mil", "Milka", "Milkmaid"]
```

But if you use `dictionary: "simple"`

```
 Product.search("Milk") #return "Milk" only
```

Comment: So if I'm primarily searching for names within text (ie 'Barack Obama') then the English dictionary won't be helping?

Comment: you should use simple as you want a permanent word not any variaion like `obama`, `oba` `Barack` only you want `Barack Obama` see my example of milk you will understand.